# 2D Array Problems with non static member reference

Tags: c++

I have a code here, but I don't know where the error is, nor have I found anything useful on the Internet.

```
#ifndef TICTACTOE_H
#define TICTACTOE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class TicTacToe {
    public:
    int lines = 3;
    int columns = 3;
    std::string grid[lines][columns] = { { "#", "#", "#" }, { "#", "#", "#" }, { "#", "#", "#" } };
};


#endif
```

I get the error message at lines and columns in the [] brackets:

> A non-static member reference must be relative to a certain object

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler must know the size of class in advance. Since `lines` and `columns` could be initialized differently for every instance of the class, they cannot be used as sizes of arrays (or else the size of class would change uncontrollably)

---

If you want to stick with arrays, you can change them to `const(expr) static` members.

```
class TicTacToe {
    public:
    constexpr static int lines = 3; 
    constexpr static int columns = 3;
    std::string grid[lines][columns] = { { "#", "#", "#" }, { "#", "#", "#" }, { "#", "#", "#" } };
};
```

Now `lines` and `columns` are immutable (cannot be changed) and common for every instance of `TicTacToe` class.

---

If you don't want constant values, you can use `std::vector`

```
class TicTacToe {
    public:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> grid = { { "#", "#", "#" }, { "#", "#", "#" }, { "#", "#", "#" } };
};
```

`std::vector` can be resized any time.